# How do I stop Alexa from reminding me of upcoming events on my calendar

Tags: alexa

I accidentally turned on a feature that has Alexa announcing upcoming calendar events two hours before . . And waking me up in the morning!  How do I turn this off?

Comment: ask alexa how to do it or command alexa to stop reminders

Comment: how do you get alexa to remind you about your calendar?